# Context root folder location in WebSphere

Tags: java, web-applications, websphere-8, contextroot

Trying to include some custom html files for a `webapp` in the `context root` folder in `WebSphere`. What's the physical directory structure/URL in `WebSphere 8.5` for the context root? In JBOSS, it used to be

`jboss\server\default\deploy\jbossweb-tomcat50.sar\ROOT.war`

Looking for the WebSphere equivalent of this location. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

A war in WebSphere will be expanded into `<WebSphere install dir>/profiles/<profile name>/config/cells/<cell name>/applications/<app name>.ear/deployments/<app name>/<module name>.war/`

If new/changed files in that directory don't get picked up you'll have to edit the compressed .ear of the app to include those files and update/redeploy it through the admin console or wsadmin.

Comment: -Thanks for the tip. Its a war file deployed through the admin console. The custom files are supplied by the client which needs to be imported during run time. Adding it to the ear/war is not an option unfortunately.